# Should I use stretch UV bounds in Smart UV?

Tags: uv-image-editor

So im trying to unwrap using smart unwrap. It looks very stretched when I turn on stretch UV bounds, but when i turn it off it looks ok, however its too small. Which one should i trust ? (im planning to export the model into substance to texture it, so im worried if stretched UVs or small UVs would be a problem? I tried to fix it by applying all transforms but it doesnt make a big difference. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I usually don't use it for the same reason - unwanted stretching/warping. That being said, for most unwraps, I only use smart-unwrap as a preliminary "first guide" and then adjust manually from there. Unselecting stretch-to-bounds will give the correct proportions.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I see. But there’s a lot of free UV space left as you can see in the uv editor. Is that a bad thing ?

Comment: Now you get to play the mimi-game of fitting all the pieces together tightly like tetris, and then scaling them up all together to fill up the space. This is a common approach, especially for video game assets, because it makes use of as much texture space as possible.

Comment: You mean fitting the unwrapped UVs of all objects into one UV map?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can use as many UV maps as you need. What I mean to say is that scaling works fine as long as it's done uniformly. Sometimes leftover space is unavoidable, the goal is to pack stuff as close together as possible (with a reasonable margin) so you can scale it all up to fill the space in the most efficient way..

Comment: Understood. Thankyou :)

Comment: No problem. I stumbled upon this guide a while back, and I've found it extremely helpful. Check it out if you like - https://artisticrender.com/the-definitive-tutorial-to-uv-mapping-in-blender/